# Slicing Array - "unexpected item in the bagging area?"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create an array that is blank up-until an index (example 700)

```
var a=[];
a[700]=true;

//produces [700:true].length==700
```

then every time I randomly add another index (very close to the last maybe 702,703,699...)

I want to (on each new index) keep the length of the array as the highest index number but get rid of every index that is not in the top ten highest indexes.

a `for` loop (where a[i]=null on everything apart from the last 10 indexes) is out of the question as this array's last index could be a rather large number that would cause iteration code to hang too long!

So I figured `Array.slice` will be instant instead...

What I am not understanding is if my array is length 700 and I do:

```
a=a.slice(a.length-10,a.length-1);
```

Why is my array now `[700:true].length==701`?

Comment: There must be a mistake: `a=a.slice(a.length-10,a.length-1);` will make your array a short one: with length 9. Can you clarify?

Comment: not sure exactly what you're logging, but `.slice` returns a new array containing the removed items and modifies the existing array. I don't believe you want to reassign in this instance.

Comment: console says [undefined × 9] but the array still equals [700:true].length==701! its the indexes that are important in preserving (you are both right and wrong)

Comment: @JesseKernaghan without reassigning I still get length 701

Comment: The array returned by `slice` always has indexes starting from `0`, it won't use the indexes from the original array.

Comment: Why are you using an array instead of an object?

Comment: you are mistaken console output is [700:true].length==701

Comment: @Barmar because the numbers are random so I would have to do a lot of code to try and reduce the object to what I want to keep (makes more sense to slice!)

Comment: If you claim to have a bug in Chrome, please post your version, and a working snippet with which you get the strange output. It is worth a question on SO, even if it turns out to be a bug in Chrome; especially then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rid of the `true` values that are not in the last 10 indexes, you could iterate the `true` elements with `forEach`, which *only* visits entries that exist. Then with `delete` you can delete those entries:

```
a.forEach ((v, i, a) => {
    if (i < a.length - 10) delete a[i];
});
```

```js
var a=[];

a[700]=true;
a[702]=true;
a[699]=true;
a[692]=true; // this one should be removed

// clean-up:
a.forEach ((v, i, a) => {
    if (i < a.length - 10) delete a[i];
});

// show last 13 elements:
for (var i=a.length-13; i<a.length; i++) {
    console.log (i, a[i]);
}
// output length
console.log('length: ', a.length);
```

Comment: I said no iteration in the question

Comment: Indeed, but your reason was *"cause iteration code to hang too long!"*: this will not be the case here, as `forEach` does not go through the whole 700 entries.

Comment: I undownvoted but your code still produces an array with length==701 (this is the reason for my question. why the weird extra item at the end of the array??!) lol

Comment: @BenMuircroft `a.length` is always 1 higher than the highest index. It's part of the definition of Javascript arrays.

Comment: That is not weird. The last used index is always one less than the reported array length, because an array starts with index 0, not 1.

Comment: ok but if I do `a=[];a[700]=true;` then the length is 700 but then if I perform any kind of slice/iteration the length becomes 701 (this does not make sense). You should be correct but the two cases seem to invalidate the facts

Comment: I just answered you below. There's no need to post the same comment twice.

Comment: Maybe Ben is soliciting my answer... But Barmar is of course right: `a[700]=true` makes the array length 701. It is a fact. Index 0 -> index 700 = 701 indices.

Comment: If this is not the output you get, then possibly you have other code running, and maybe in a different order than you think. Test it with just the 3 lines of code needed. If you can reproduce your claim, please post a snippet or jsfiddle as proof. My snippet proves that setting `a[702]` will set the `a.length` to 703.

Comment: I have no code running I'm typing into chromes console (on this page)! My version of Chrome appears to be telling lies!

Comment: So what are you typing in the console: `a=[]`, then `a[700]=true` and then `a.length`?

Comment: @trincot I think top 10 doesn't means top 10 indices.

Comment: @mortezaT, I think it does mean that. The OP wrote *"the top ten highest indexes"*, and his code (cf. `a.length-10`) also suggest this is what he intended.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop that goes from `0` to `a.length`. When you create a sparse array, only the indexes that you assigned to will be in the keys, so you can use `Object.keys(a)` to get them. You can sort this and loop over them.

```
var indexes = Object.keys(a).map(Number).sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
});
indexes.slice(0, -10).forEach(function(i) {
    delete a[i];
});
```

You seem to be somewhat confused about how length gets set. It's always set to 1 more than the highest index. Try running the following snippet, you'll see that length is `701` even without doing any slicing or iterating.

```js
var a = [];
a[700] = true;
console.log(a.length);
```

Comment: your code still produces an array with length==701 (what's with that!?) it's puzzling the hell out of me!

Comment: Why is that puzzling? When you assign `a[0]`, length is `1`. When you assign `a[10]`, length is `11`. And so on.

Comment: @BenMuircroft, that is normal. Index 0 is counted as well. All JavaScript arrays are like that.

Comment: ok but if I do a=[];a[700]=true; then the length is 700 but then if I perform any kind of slice/iteration the length becomes 701 (this does not make sense). You should be correct but the two cases seem to invalidate the facts

Comment: @BenMuircroft You're wrong. When I do `a=[]; a[700]=true;` then the length is 701. Slice/iteration has nothing to do with it.

Comment: On your above point I wrote `a=[];a[700]=true;` then via your and my reasoning the length would be 701 but it is not its 700

Comment: Try the snippet I just added to my answer.

Comment: That's not what chromes console says! open chrome and try

Comment: I did it in Chrome first before I wrote the snippet.

Comment: hmmm very very odd

Comment: Can you post a screenshot showing the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @BenMuircroft `JavaScript` arrays indices starts from 0 so if you set value for `array[n]` then the length of array will be `n + 1`. If you want to get assigned values length then you can use `Obejct.keys(array).length`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=[]; // empty array (length 0)
a[700] = true; // You fill the value "true" to the case with index 700 in the array "a"
a.length; // 701 : logic because we had a value on the 700 index
a = a.slice(a.length-10, a.length-1); //[undefined × 9] 9 elements undefined
// that's create a shallow copy of the array 
// from the index 691(included) to 700(not included)
a.length; // 9
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go all the way blind then this could be the answer. But the problem would be this will go down all the way to index `0` if the array has value index length is less than `topNToKeep`:

```js
var array = [];
var someBigNumber = 999;
var topNToKeep = 10;
array[someBigNumber] = true;

var count = 100;
(function _repeat() {
  var index = parseInt(someBigNumber * Math.random()) + someBigNumber;
  array = addIndexAndKeepTopN(array, index, topNToKeep);
  if (count-- > 0)
    _repeat();
}());

console.log(array);

function addIndexAndKeepTopN(array, index, topNToKeep) {
  array[index] = true;
  var newArray = [];
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0 && topNToKeep > 0; i--) {
    if (i in array) {
      newArray[i] = true;
      topNToKeep--;
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

But the best way I can find now would be to use `Object.keys` method:

```js
console.clear();
var array = [];
var someBigNumber = 1000;
var topNToKeep = 10;
array[someBigNumber] = true;

var count = 100;
(function _repeat() {
  var index = parseInt(someBigNumber * Math.random()) + someBigNumber;
  array = addIndexAndKeepTopN(array, index, topNToKeep);
  if (count-- > 0)
    _repeat();
}());

console.log(Object.keys(array).length, Object.keys(array), array);

function addIndexAndKeepTopN(array, index, topNToKeep) {
  array[index] = true;
  var keys = Object.keys(array);
  if (keys.length >= topNToKeep) {
    array = [];
    keys = keys.map(Number)
      .sort().reverse().splice(0, topNToKeep);
    keys.forEach(k => array[k] = true);
  }
  return array;
}
```